# GitLab issues connecting to us-gov-west-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, boto, gitlab-ci

There's a GitLab.com update rolling out today, and I'm seeing issues connecting to a particular AWS region with Ansible: **us-gov-west-1**.

This is odd, since in my CI job I'm able to use the AWS CLI just fine:

CI build step:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances
```

Output (truncated):

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    }, 
                    "PublicDnsName": "ec2-...
```

The very build step is as follows, notice that it fails to connect to the region:

CI build step:

```
$ ansible-playbook -vvv -i inventory/ec2.py -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=aws-keypairs/gitlab_keypair.pem playbooks/deploy.yml
```

Output (truncated)

```
Using /builds/me/my-project/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! Attempted to execute "inventory/ec2.py" as inventory script: Inventory script (inventory/ec2.py) had an execution error: region name: us-gov-west-1 likely not supported, or AWS is down.  connection to region failed. 
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Is anyone else seeing this?

It was working this morning.  Any idea why this might be failing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small Python script to dive deeper into boto. When I googled how to list the regions,I was reminded of the differences in boto 2 vs boto 3. Then, I reviewed the mechanism I was using to install boto. It looks like the boto installation was the problem.

Here’s the buggy version of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: ansible/ansible:ubuntu1604

test_aws:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install python 
    - apt-get -y install python-boto python-pip
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - 'aws ec2 describe-instances'

deploy_app:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install python 
    - apt-get -y install python-boto python-pip
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - 'chmod 400 aws-keypairs/gitlab_keypair.pem'
    - 'ansible-playbook -vvv -i inventory/ec2.py -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=aws-keypairs/gitlab_keypair.pem playbooks/deploy.yml'
```

And here’s the fixed version:

```
image: ansible/ansible:ubuntu1604

all_in_one:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install python python-pip
    - pip install boto==2.48.0
    - pip install awscli
    - pip install ansible==2.2.2.0
  script:
    - 'chmod 400 aws-keypairs/gitlab_keypair.pem'
    - 'aws ec2 describe-instances'
    - 'python ./boto_debug.py'
    - 'ansible-playbook -vvv -i inventory/ec2.py -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=aws-keypairs/gitlab_keypair.pem playbooks/deploy.yml'
```

Notice that I switched from using `apt-get install` to using `pip install`. Hopefully others will come across this post in the future and avoid installing boto with `apt-get -y install python-boto`!